# Handle changes in database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, contentobserver

I've got next task.

There is an application A with the database in it's own system memory, for example /data/data/com.exapmle.a/databases/db

Also there is an application B. And the task of application B - to track changes in one table of database of application A.

If A - is SMS applictaion, I could add rights into manifest and add ContentObserver to the table, that I need to track on, and in onChange method I could track all the changes.

But how to make the same if A - is not SMS application?

Device is rooted.

Comment: Is A your application ? can you be more specific about A please

Comment: No, A application is not mine

Comment: One solution I can think of is polling but then it consumes much battery.

Answer (score 0):

Content observers have been replaced by content providers.  I would start with [I can't view logs from my database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056386/i-cant-view-logs-from-my-database/17960915#17960915).  This should cover most of the issues.  Make sure you check out the first link, it has the gist on sharing and  sqlite issues.

Hope this helps.