# Android: What is better, using a SQLiteCursorLoader or implementing a ContentProvider?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to show the contents of a SQLite database in a ListView, and seeking the web I have found 2 options:

- Using [SQLiteCursorLoader](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex/blob/master/README.markdown), or
- Implementing a Content Provider like [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-populating-listview-from-sqlite-database-using-cursorloader-loadermanager-and-content-provider/)

Android Dev docs say a content provider is not needed to access a database, and it should be use to share data with other apps (what I do not need). What do you think is better in terms of efficiency, error-prone and simplicity?

Thank you guys!

Comment: `Android Dev docs say a content provider is not needed to access a database, and it should be use to share data with other apps (what I do not need)`  The answer is in the question.  Use a loader.

Comment: Yes but I've seen developers who use a content provider, and I wonder if there is some advantage

Comment: I tried the two methods (Loader with ContentProvider and SimpleCursorAdapter), and I think this is really better to use a Loader with a ContentProvider. ContentProvider implementation is easy and always the same. It will save you from many issues (cursor lifecycle for example)

Comment: Thanks @buzeeg, my question went for this way. I will try with ContentProvider first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously sharing data is the most frequent reason people put for using a content provider.

- There have been some bugs in sqlite and multiple users, although not absolute usually a content provider is in a single thread and can solve this issue and yes this is when your sharing data between apps.
- A content provider can give you a level of abstraction and possibly have less code maintenance, especially with internal database structure changes.
- It allows you to perform asynchronous queries with a CursorLoader, off loading your UI Activities, which is the design recommendation.
- In conjunction with a database helper, it makes it easier to get your table and column names correct and narrows down where you have to look and maintain code.
- The use of a database helper or contract between your application and content provider can provide some security, as you provide the methods to your and any other application on how the data get updated.
- This can also give you some better data integrity, dependent on how complex your database structure is.  It leaves the guess work out of was I supposed to update Table A first and then Table B or the other way around.
- It can help with table joins and views so you only have to figure that out once and represent them as a URI.
- You can created a URI to handle a raw query inside of a content provider to supply results, that otherwise might have been hard to write with the normal URI structure as it's presented in most tutorials.  This is also useful if you have to write a correlated query.

Comment: Very complete and useful answer, @Peter. Thanks!