# What is safe way to populate a listview from a SQL database without a content provider (or do i have to make one)

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am writing an android application that populates a list view from an sqlite database.

I saw that SimpleCursorAdapte is [a somewhat deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) as it does queries on the UI thread.  The recommendation is "As an alternative, use LoaderManager with a CursorLoader."

However it seems that (I could be wrong...) CursorLoader uses a content provider to manage database access.  Since nothing in my database needs to be accessed by other applications, this seem unnecessary and overly complicated. Is this my only option in implementing thread safe and synchronized access to the database,

or

Is it still safe to use a DAO and use asynctask when running its methods (with minSdkVersion >= 11).

Comment: I tried the two methods (Loader with ContentProvider and SimpleCursorAdapter), and I think this is really better to use a Loader with a ContentProvider. ContentProvider implementation is easy and always the same. It will save you from many issues (cursor lifecycle for example)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I might as well put in the extra work for future simplicity

Answer (score 0):

The android SDK is making it harder and harder to put things that should be services or asynctasks on the UI thread.  This is the direction they are moving in.

See my answer on [cursorloader vs content provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17866906/android-what-is-better-using-a-sqlitecursorloader-or-implementing-a-contentpro/17913991#17913991)